# How can I ensure my UITableView data update function is called only once when app is displayed again (from background start, or launch)?

Tags: iphone, ios, viewdidload, nsnotificationcenter

How can I ensure my table data function is called only once when app is displayed again (from background start, or launch)?

That is, I want to have my table data refreshed when the user clicks on the application icon, and only once.  So the requirement would be:
a) update method in controller called only once after application icon is clicked by user
b) to be valid irrespective of whether the user is (i) starting app for the first time, (ii) coming back from background, (iii) any other means of the user requesting the app come back to the foreground.

The issue I currently have with my implementation is that the data update is being called twice in the case where the app is coming back from background, so I basically want to improve on this.  The way I'm doing currently, which is flawed is:

```
- (void)updateEventData {
    // UPDATE CODE HERE
}
- (void)becomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification {
    [self updateEventData];
    [self.tableView reloadData];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];  
    [self updateEventData];

    // Auto Refresh Data - Handle Case where App becomes active from background & you want to refresh data
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(becomeActive:)
                                                 name:UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification
                                               object:nil];

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can implement it in following way:

1) Take one variable in NSUserDefault.
2) Set it's value FALSE when app is launch for the first time.
3) Get the value of NSUserDefault variable in respective view controller. And if it's value if FALSE then call update method.
4) Now, when app become Active, then set the variable value TRUE.
5) Get it's value in respective view controller. And if's value is TRUE then don't call update method.
6) So, update method will be called only once.

Hope it will be helpful to you. May be there is some minor changes.

Let me know in case of any difficulty.

Comment: so I would set it to FALSE in the appDelegate didFinishLaunchingWithOptions method, and set it back to true in the applicationWillTerminate method?  Would this be a solid way to track the true initial start, and exit (not going to background) of the app?

Comment: Yes, you can do like this. OR you can take simple boolean variable in appDelegate method. And use it in your app and check it's value for True/False. And call the method accordingly.

Comment: thanks Nishant - just posted (in my own answer) what may be even simpler - it seems to work?

Comment: Hi Greg, I think this is the simple way. Because, we are doing the process in different view controller and also based on app launch and app active/deactive.

Comment: Hey Nishant - actually when you said "this" is the simple way, which way were you referring to?  wasn't sure  :)

Comment: The way of taking variable in AppDelegate and set/reset in respective view controller. And call method accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Well what i understand from your question that you only want to update the table data when you start your application by clicking the app icon on the iPhone.Well First understand the execution of the app, the main function is called first and then in your app delegate

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {    

    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    [self postNotification];
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];

    return YES;
}
```

you can post the notification in this method as its called once.
And more over if you want to do this by your own way in the ViewDidLoad method, then i think you must also remove the observer of notification,i think that may be the reason that its being called twice,because you are not removing notification.

Comment: didn't quite follow Sabby - I'm assuming why things are getting called twice for me is because in the case of an app start up I'm getting both the normal viewDidLoad triggering it as well as the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification.  I put the UIApplicationDidBecomeActiveNotification in to cover the case where the application only went to background and wasn't triggering the viewDidLoad...

Comment: @Greg thats fine dear,you handled that...Now you resolved your problem

Answer (score 0):

As part of writing this question and reviewing answers I think I've got probably a good solution...

- Create an instance variable/property "initialLoad"
- Set it to TRUE first thing in viewDidLoad
- Then in the becomeActive method do the following:

Code:

```
- (void)becomeActive:(NSNotification *)notification {
    if (!self.initialLoad) {
        [self updateEventData];
        [self.tableView reloadData];
    }
    self.initialLoad = false;
}
```

Seems to work ok...